# Ubuntu packages search for trusty-updates ($CURRENTVERSION-updates)

Tags: upgrade, updates, package-management

I find the website http://packages.ubuntu.com/ quite useful when I am looking for information on packages (changelog, dependencies...).

I do my upgrades at the command line and yesterday I was proposed an update of xterm, so I wanted to go check out what were the changes in this new release.

Unfortunately, this new package was from trusty-updates, which is not listed in http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Is there a similar ressource where I could get that information ?

Comment: Is http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xterm  and source http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/xterm not you looking for?

Comment: @Pandya This is weird because yesterday the changelog was not up to date with the version in proposed (297-1ubuntu1). So I didn't know what would the update do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out that the website needed just a bit of time to upgrade.

Now the page is filled with links for `trusty-updates` `trusty-backports` and `utopic`.